# How do I slice an array from the output from RollCor in R?

Tags: r, correlation, data-manipulation, rolling-computation

I'm trying to get a rolling correlation output between two variables `DGS10` and `SP500`, but I'm getting a correlation matrix output for every row. Is there a way to slice it to only get the real value [0][1]. I'm new to R from Python...

Packages & Variables

```
library(quantmod)
getSymbols('DGS10',src='FRED')
getSymbols('SP500',src='FRED')
```

Code

````
```{r}
merge(DGS10, SP500) %>%
  na.omit() %>%
  roll_cor(width=5)
```
````

Output

```
          DGS10     SP500
DGS10 1.0000000 0.8542177
SP500 0.8542177 1.0000000

, , 6

          DGS10     SP500
DGS10 1.0000000 0.9104856
SP500 0.9104856 1.0000000

, , 7

          DGS10     SP500
DGS10 1.0000000 0.9672053
SP500 0.9672053 1.0000000
```

Desired Output

```
5       0.8542177
6       0.9104856
7       0.9672053
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest first time I'm seeing array like this - `[1:2, 1:2, 1:2496]`. I see that it is impossible to get values from it with multidimension indexes like `[1, 2, 1:2496]`. It has length of 9984 (2496 * 4) so you can pull desired values with:

```
merge(DGS10, SP500) %>%
  na.omit() %>%
  roll_cor(width=5) %>%
  `[`(seq(2, length(.), 4)) %>%
  as.data.frame()
```

As it may look little vague to you because you are new to `R` it is equivalent to:

```
temp <-
  merge(DGS10, SP500) %>%
  na.omit() %>%
  roll_cor(width=5)

temp[seq(2, length(temp), 4)] %>%
  as.data.frame()
```

But I will advise you to use `tidyquant` library. Then you can get your results in more clear way:

```
library(tidyquant)

tq_get(c('DGS10', 'SP500'), get = 'economic.data') %>%
  spread(symbol, price) %>%
  na.omit() %>%
  tq_mutate_xy(
    x = DGS10,
    y = SP500,
    mutate_fun = runCor,
    n = 5
  )
```